# How to draw X Sign with SVG+CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, web, frontend

I need to create an animation of "X" checkmark sign (for failure).

I've found a great example of an animated "v" checkmark sign (for success).
The code is using curve-bezier design.
I've tried reading and trying to do an X sign but with no success.

Can you please help me ?

The link for the "v" checkmark is:
http://codepen.io/haniotis/pen/KwvYLO

```css
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}
.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}
@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
  <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
</svg>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to change the path definition to form an "X" and change the dash pattern and offset to compensate for the changed path length.

I've gone simple here an just have the two legs of the X being drawn at the same time.  With an extra `<path>` element and some extra CSS you can make it draw the X in two steps.

```css
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}
.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 29;
  stroke-dashoffset: 29;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}
@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
  <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
  <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M16 16 36 36 M36 16 16 36" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot! From where can I learn about doing stuff like this ? Do you have a great tutorial for this ?

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web describing how SVG paths and how to create a line drawing animation using the dash pattern trick. Just use your favourite search engine :)

Comment: #FF0000 instead of #7ac142 is likely more error-like than now :)